# Migrated Wordpress Site Improperly - wrdp?

Tags: php, wordpress

A few days ago I migrated my Wordpress site from one Hostgator hosting to a new Hostgator hosting (same shared hosting plan).

I believe I didn't do it properly.

I used a Wordpress plugin called UpdraftPlus to backup the Database, Plugins, Themes, Uploads, and Others. Then I installed Wordpress on the new hosting, installed the UpdraftPlus plugin, and uploaded the stuff I backed up.

Actually, the site was restored fully, and it seems to work fine (apart from 1 error I can't work out how to fix).

Here's the error:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user '*****'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home3/****/public_html/*****.com/wp-content/themes/PricerrTheme/single-job.php on line 419

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home3/*****/public_html/*****.com/wp-content/themes/PricerrTheme/single-job.php on line 419

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home3/*****/public_html/*****.com/wp-content/themes/PricerrTheme/single-job.php on line 422
```

The error occurs on the section where customer feedback is displayed. But anyway, I just thought I'd mention that error, if anyone gets any ideas on how to fix it.

But my actual question here is about the "config.php" file for the theme, and the "wp-config.php" file for the wordpress installation. There's a difference between them, and I'm wondering if I should change it.

Here it is (this is in config.php for the theme):

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'olduser_wrdp2';
$db_pass = 'onepass';
$db_name = 'olduser_wrdp2';
```

And this is in the wp-config.php for the wordpress installation:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'newuser_wrdp2');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'newuser_wrdp2');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'differentpass');
```

Basically, the information between these two files is different. The first config shows the info from my old hosting, but the wp-config shows the info from my new hosting (I had a different username on the old hosting, and a different username on the new hosting, so the databases start with a different username -> olduser_wrdp2 versus newuser_wrdp2).

Should I change the info in the theme config file (olduser_wrdp2) to be the same as in the wordpress config file (newuser_wrdp2)? Any other useful info you could give me?

Thank you

Comment: I should start by looking for a theme that does not use the `mysql_` database extension. Every time you use that database extension 
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Change the Theme config to match the `config.php`

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly. I did it. Tell me, does anything else come to mind that I should check out in my situation? And do you have any ideas on how I can fix the other error I get (Access denied for user... etc)?

Comment: Make a backup and change settings in theme config file to see if it helps fix the error. P.S. my personal concern in this situation would be the theme that uses its own config for whatever reason.